# Overlay UI over another UWP app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Is it possible to show an overlay over another UWP app from my UWP background task? I need to show some alert in another UWP app once i detect a behavior in it. I have a separate question for detecting behavior though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access another app from your UWP background task. Windows 10 SDK allows app to app communication but you can not change UI of another app or display any alert. It may be considered as a part of their app security.